# Tilt shape container in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image]

I'm trying to set tilt container and set image in container.I set some math calculations as per my knowledge but still I am not achieving my result.
I am trying with some math functions and code.

Here is my small part of flutter code:-

```
final kInnerDecoration = BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.white,
    border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
  );

  final kGradientBoxDecoration = BoxDecoration(
    gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.black, Colors.redAccent]),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
  );
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50)),
                Transform(
                  alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                  transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(
                    3.1415926535897932 / 4,
                  ),
                  child: Container(
                    // margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                      child: Container(
                        child: Transform(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(
                            -.1415926535897932 / 4,
                          ),
                          child: Image.asset(
                            "assests/11.png",
                            height: 100,
                            width: 100,
                          ),
                        ),
                        decoration: kInnerDecoration,
                      ),
                    ),
                    height: 100,
                    width: 150,
                    decoration: kGradientBoxDecoration,
                  ),
                ),

              ],
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Text("Bottom"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

How can achieve my result?

Thank x!

Comment: I think you can easily do it with shapeBorder or ClipPath with Stack

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Thank x for your comment but add more code and add proper solutions, please.

Answer (score 0):

Try ClipPath.

btw if you want to change TiltCliper and see changes quickly with hot reload, set shouldReclip during development.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Pet Profile"),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ClipPath(
              clipper: const TiltCliper(
                bottomRight: Offset(0, -50),
              ),
              child: Image.asset(
                "assets/images/puppy.png",
              ),
            ),
            const Expanded(
              child: Text("Bottom"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TiltCliper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  const TiltCliper({
    this.topLeft = const Offset(0, 0),
    this.topRight = const Offset(0, 0),
    this.bottomLeft = const Offset(0, 0),
    this.bottomRight = const Offset(0, 0),
  });

  final Offset topLeft;
  final Offset topRight;
  final Offset bottomLeft;
  final Offset bottomRight;

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path();
    final x1 = topLeft.dx;
    final y1 = topLeft.dy;
    final x2 = size.width + topRight.dx;
    final y2 = topRight.dy;
    final x3 = size.width + bottomRight.dx;
    final y3 = size.height + bottomRight.dy;
    final x4 = bottomLeft.dx;
    final y4 = size.height + bottomLeft.dy;

    path.moveTo(x1, y1);
    path.lineTo(x2, y2);
    path.lineTo(x3, y3);
    path.lineTo(x4, y4);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```